# Writing ( and publishing ) Batch Job

Tags: civimember, contributions

I expect this is a common problem,

Treasurer get loads on contributions in CSV format ( Contact ID / Amount / Date )

Bulk loading contributions via CSV is completely detached from membership renewal.

As memberships are set to go 'grace' on expiry I think a script like

Search membership in grace
If contribution made and receipt date > membership expiry date
   set membership status to current , 
   set expiry to end next period, 
   link contribution to membership

I don't think this is too challenging in SQL  ( I haven't looked at API ing it )

So now the question,  there are batch jobs - how are they created / structured ?

Answer (score 1):

I have rewritten the code found in this thread https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=19322.0
'Collins22' chicago-orienteering.org/civicrm_code.htm

to suit my specific purposes.  It isn't a civicrm extension nor uses API so far from architecturally pure, but it can be run as a php cron job so does the what is needed.

I have published the code on github https://github.com/alanef/civicrm-contribs-to-membership maybe it is of use to others - maybe some one wants to contribute and write it properly.